# Нужна помощь с тг ботом

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, бот, telebot

Бот отвечает на команду 'Придумать пароль'. Но проблема в том, что делает он это через сообщение. К примеру я пишу 'Придумать пароль', ещё одно любое сообщение и только затем он отвечает. С чем это связано?[image: скриншот]

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def menu(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'придумать пароль':
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, key_pass_func)
def key_pass_func(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key_pass = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Генерация пароля', callback_data='start')
    keyboard.add(key_pass)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Для подтверждения нажми кнопку', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Может потому что вы не читали, что такое `bot.register_next_step_handler`?

Comment: Дай вопросу нормальный заголовок, отражающий суть проблемы

Comment: `register_next_step_handler` с японского - зарегестрироват обработка следующий шаг, что вроде как значит, что действие произойдет на следующем шаге?.

Comment: elif message.text.lower() == 'придумать пароль':
  bot.key_pass_func(message) если я вас правильно понял?

Comment: @user404364 а зачем `bot.key_pass_func`? Просто `key_pass_func`

Answer (score 1):

вместо register next step, напишите key_pass_func(message)

Comment: register next step перебрасывает на функцию, заменить его на название самой функции нельзя, ошибка в коде

Comment: @user404364 `bot.register_next_step_handler` не перебрасывает на функцию, а вызывает её при следующем сообщении. Какая у вас ошибка?

Comment: @timur с пониманием, как по мне

Comment: спасибо, только что понял в чём ошибка